# Javascript object value undefined when accessing "attribute"?

Tags: javascript

Why is this `undefined`:

```
var testObj = {
   CONSTANT: "blah",
   someVal: this.CONSTANT
}
console.debug(testObj.someVal); // prints "undefined"
```

If it has to do with the fact that I am actually creating a new prototype and therefore the `this` keyword is not working, then I'd also like to know the following:

I am using Dean Edward's [base.js](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/) and I am trying to do something similar to the above: I have an object that extends Base:

```
Test = Base.extend({
  testObj: {
   someVal: this.CONSTANT
  }
  CONSTANT: "blah";
});
var test1 = new Test();
console.debug(test1.testObj); // someVal is undefined
```

In the above, if I do `someVal: "blah"` this it works as expected; I'm just not sure why I can't access `this.CONSTANT`.  If its because `this` is applied to the scope of `testObj` and not `Test`, then how do I solve this (I tried setting a `that: this` variable, with no luck)?

**Update:** based on the answers I see that I am doing this wrong.  My question now is: using the base.js model, is there a way to have "class-level" constants that are accessible from within the same class (outside of functions)?

Answer (score 5):

`this` references the `window` not the object.

```
var CONSTANT =  "blah";
var testObj = {
   someVal: this.CONSTANT
}
testObj.someVal; // blah
```

You can't access the object itself with object notation.

---

You a function to change the scope of this:

```
function testObjCreator() {
  this.CONSTANT = "blah";
  return ({
      val: this.CONSTANT
  })
}
var a = new testObjCreator()
a.val; // blah
```

Comment: good point: what about the 2nd case (which is what I'm really interested in). looking at the base.js (the Animal class example) Dean uses "this" to access the object itself.  thanks.

Comment: in the base.js example I gave, it definitely seems like a scope issue to me ("this" is not referencing the right scope)..I just don't know how to fix that.

Comment: In the second example, this is still the window

Comment: is there a way to access the CONSTANT?

Comment: I've added an update to show how you could change the scope of this

Answer (score 0):

"this" is (locally) defined only within a function which has been called as a method.

base.js uses "this" only within a function definition, where it designates the object on which the function was called as a method. Your examples don't contain any function definitions.

Comment: good point; is there a way to do what I am trying to do? basically having class level constants that I can access within the same class?